# Java CRUD - delete with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

So I've got a problem with delete query. Here's my method:

```
public void delete(int x) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("delete from Event where event_id=" + x);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    sqlQuery.executeUpdate();
}
```

And here's a part of my JSP file :

```
<a href="deleteEvent.do?id=<c:out value='${c.eventId}'/>">Delete</a>
```

And here's my controller:

```
EventDao eDao = new EventDao();

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            eDao.delete(id);
}
```

When I click on "Delete" link it opens localhost:8080/App/deleteEvent.do?id=8 but it doesn't delete the record in my database. If I add response.sendRedirect("list"); it redirects me to 'list' webpage so I think controller works. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try before committing the transaction 
First execute the update and commit the transaction

Comment: I did it like this : session.createSQLQuery("delete from Event where event_id=" + x).executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
but there's error Stack Trace
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Comment: @majkoz0rd  instead of using sql related query builder just use createQuery and executeList